# Jquery Adding an "Other" to a form - Passing correct Variable into database

Tags: jquery

I am using Select in a form and have the "Other" option that displays the "Other" text input box. However I only want to save the actual value in the same column in my table so I need to make sure the "value" of the "Other" text input gets passed to the MySQL table not the content of the selected which is obviously "Other"

```html
<div>
  <select class="element select small" id="prop_title" name="prop_title">
    <option value="Mr" >Mr</option>
    <option value="Mrs" >Mrs</option>
    <option value="Sir" >Sir</option>
    <option value="Lord" >Lord</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
  <div id="prop_title_other" style="display: none; margin-top:15px;">
    <label class="description" for="prop_title">Proprietor Title (Other)</label>
    <input type="text" id="prop_title" class="element text small" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('#prop_title').change(function() 
{
  $('#prop_title_other').css('display', ($(this).val() == 'Other') ? 'block' : 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$(this)` becomes the object of text box. That is y you have that problem. Change `$(this)` to a local variable

```
$('#prop_title').change(function() 
{
  var item=$(this);
   $('#prop_title_other').css('display', (item.val() == 'Other') ? 'block' : 'none');
});
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/GbGbU/

Comment: Firstly, jsfiddle, never seen it before, very cool! Secondly, I still have the problem with two parts of the form with the same id and name so I cant be sure which one is going to be used when I submit the Form

Comment: @M1CreativeDeveloper: The JS fiddle has the same code (but fixed) you mentioned in your question. I guess you have some other script error in your page. Check firebug console.

Comment: Thanks. I had forgotten to add a "name" field to the text box, but I think Iam failing to explain correctly. When I submit the form I have two fields now with the name "prop_title" and of course it is un-predictable which one will be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#prop_title').change(function() 
{
  var display;

  if ($(this).val() == 'Other') {
       display = "none";      
  }  else { display = "block"};

  $('#prop_title_other').css('display', display);

});
```